# Prevent Org from escaping latex results

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

During export, Org generates this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]

\node[initial,state]   (A)              \{\$q$_{\text{0}}$\$\};
\node[state]           (B) [right of=A] \{\$q$_{\text{1}}$\$\};
\node[state]           (C) [right of=B] \{\$q$_{\text{2}}$\$\};
\node[accepting,state] (D) [below of=A] \{\$q$_{\text{3}}$\$\};
\node[accepting,state] (E) [below of=C] \{\$q$_{\text{4}}$\$\};

  \path (A) edge [loop above] node \{\$b\$\} (A)
            edge              node \{\$a\$\} (B)
        (B) edge              node \{\$a\$\} (C)
            edge              node \{\$a\$\} (D)
            edge              node \{\$b\$\} (E)
        (C) edge              node \{\$a\$\} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

from this:

```
#+HEADER: :exports results
#+HEADER: :results (by-backend (pdf "latex") (t "raw"))
#+BEGIN_SRC latex
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                      semithick]

    \node[initial,state]   (A)              {$q_0$};
    \node[state]           (B) [right of=A] {$q_1$};
    \node[state]           (C) [right of=B] {$q_2$};
    \node[accepting,state] (D) [below of=A] {$q_3$};
    \node[accepting,state] (E) [below of=C] {$q_4$};

    \path (A) edge [loop above] node {$b$} (A)
              edge              node {$a$} (B)
          (B) edge              node {$a$} (C)
              edge              node {$a$} (D)
              edge              node {$b$} (E)
          (C) edge              node {$a$} (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+END_SRC
```

Where `by-backend` looks like this:

```
(defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
  `(cl-case (when (boundp 'backend)
              (org-export-backend-name backend))
     ,@body))
```

This behavior is present in Org version 8.2.10, but it didn't happen on my laptop with potentially different version, which I don't remember.

How to prevent it from escaping the results?

Comment: Maybe you need to update your `by-backend`? See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-09/msg00118.html

Comment: @rvf0068 thanks, it wasn't just this, the backend name also changed to `latex` from `pdf`. You can make your comment into a reply, if you want.