# Export org file to html and latex

Tags: org-mode, latex

I want to use only one org file to export both `.tex` and `.html`.

I use `begin_latex` in my org files to embed maths and I can use <kbd>C-c '</kbd> to use the `org-edit-src-code` feature which help fast typing latex(Thus I can use Auctex and more). But it seems that the contents in `begin_latex` will not be formatted into equations when exporting to html.

After I read the org manual, I know that latex code can be embedded without `begin_latex`, and can be export to both `html` and `tex`. In this situation, I have to use `cdlatex` to type latex in a org file and can *not* use the `org-edit-src-code` feature, which means that I lost the latex code highlighting when typing. That really annoys me.

Any suggestions about this?

Comment: What I do in this case: `#+begin_src latex ... #+end_src` and then use the `by-backend` macro to export the LaTeX code depending on what back-end is currently active. For example see my question here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19419/prevent-org-from-escaping-latex-results (also note the related problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code in a `begin_src latex` block with `:results drawer :export results` in the header. Here is an example:

```
#+begin_src latex :results drawer :exports results
  \[  \frac{1}{2} \]
#+end_src
```

This way you can edit the latex with full editor support and end up with raw latex. Best of both worlds!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks great!  It seems that I should add an org template for writing this `:result` thing quickly. Now I find a new question like [org-html-export-does-not-recognize-custom-latex-macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038247/org-html-export-does-not-recognize-custom-latex-macros). Is there an elegant way to share the custom latex commands in both latex and html export ?

Comment: I guess you need to read http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html

Comment: Seems that adjusting  `org-html-mathjax-template` is needed, thanks for your hints!